# Play audio and video in Cordova application which works in Android, IOS and desktop devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova, html5-video, cordova-plugins

I need to play audio and video in my Hybrid Application which should works in Android, IOS and windows desktops. Application is build on top of JQuery Mobile wrapped with Cordova for Mobile.

HTML5 video tag works in browser but not in Android. I browsed and found few plugins specific to a platform(Android) where we have to add code in .java file which I don't want to do.

```
<video width="350" height="150" controls>
            <source  type="video/m4v" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" >
 </video>
```

I also looked at Media API of Cordova and I found that works with Audio ( http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_media_media.md.html ).

Is there any way by which I can play Audio as well as Video that works in Android, IOS and desktop browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of finding problems, this solution works for me, in desktop and mobile browsers and Cordova on iOS and Android. It addresses the following findings:

- On iOS, `<audio>` works, but without volume control.
- On Android, `<audio>` doesn't work, the Media plugin is needed.
- On iOS, the *src* attribut of the `<audio>` element can be used for the *Media* object, on Android the *src* property of the js *Audio* object works.
- The *setVolume()* method must be called directly after *play()* to take effect.
- On Android, the Media event handlers were never called. That's bad, because according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media#mediarelease), the *release()* method should be called after playback. *No solution yet for this issue.*

The example has a static audio element with a src path relative to *index.html*, inside Cordova's *www* folder. On startup the script checks for Cordova and sets up a *DeviceReady* handler, if so. Then the audio element is found and gets played via *playAudio()*.

HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Audio Example</title>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<script>
    var config = {
        audioVolume: 0.25
    }

    // Use onDeviceReady if we run in Cordova
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        if (window.Cordova) {
            console.log("Cordova found");
            document.addEventListener('DeviceReady', start, false);
        } else {
            console.log("Cordova not found, using pure html audio")
            start();
        }
    }, false);

    function start() {
        var audioElement = document.querySelector("audio");
        playAudio(audioElement);
    }

    function playAudio(ae) {
        var source, me, successFunction, onSuccess, onError;

        onSuccess = function() {
            console.log('Playing ' + ae.src + ' at volume ' + config.audioVolume);
            me.release();
        }

        onError = function(e) {
            console.log('ERROR on playing ' + ae.src + ' at volume ' + config.audioVolume
                        + ': (' + e.code + ') ' + e.message);
        }

        onStatusChange = function(s){
            console.log('Media status changed to ' + s);
            if (s === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) onSuccess();
        }

       // If running in Cordova and Media plugin loaded, use that
        if (typeof Media === "function") { 
            source = device.platform === 'iOS'
                        ? ae.getAttribute('src')     // relative path
                        : ae.src;                    // file-url, platform-dependant
            me = new Media(source, onSuccess, onError, onStatusChange);
            me.play();     
            me.setVolume(config.audioVolume);   
        } else {
            ae.volume = config.audioVolume;
            ae.play();
        }
    }

</script>
```

HTML body:

```
<audio src="sounds/mysound.mp3"></audio>
```